Deploying an ERC20 Contract: Invalid Opcode Error
I'm trying to deploy an ERC20 contract, but I keep getting an invalid opcode error. Below is my contract and a screenshot from REMIX:
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address initialOwner
    ) ERC20(name, symbol) Ownable(initialOwner) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _burn(from, amount);
    }
}



can you confirm what solidity version you used to compile this with?

0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6 @Zaryab

Try to use a more recent VM, I suggest Shanghai or Cancun, both  should work:

